# List files not in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database files for holding details about files in different folders and the field flink holds the path of the file.Now i want to run a search both in the folder and database and find the files that are not listed in the database.Is this possible using PHP MYSQL.I have written a sample code but it doesnt seem to work.Please note that files folder contains number of subdirectories as well.

```
<?php

include("dbfiles.php");
$directory='files/';
// Query database
$query = 'SELECT `flink` FROM `files`';
$result = mysqli_query($fmysqli, $query);
$db = []; // create empty array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    array_push($db, $row[0]);
// Check files
$files1 = scandir($directory);
if ( $files1 !== false ) {
    foreach ($files1 as $i => $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $db)) {
            // File exists in both
            echo '   Exists   '.$value;
        } else {
            // File doesn't exist in database
            echo '  Not Exists  '.$value;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

The result is something unexpected there is a file inside BT363 Folder the path is as follows `files/BT363/BT363-Metabolic Engineering and Synthetic Biology-Class Slide--Module 4-admin-admin.pptx`

But i am getting the output as

Not Exists . Not Exists .. Not Exists BT363

Comment: `... Is this possible using PHP MySQL?` - Yes

Comment: Despite appearances, this isn't a free code writing service

Comment: I have written code can you help me trouble shoot now?

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the files in a directory by doing this:

```
$files = scandir($path);
```

Then query your database for the file information you want and then loop through it and compare the current iteration and find that value in $files.

Comment: I am getting wierd output can you help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by weird output?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Due to the extreme lack of specific detail in your question, my response is going to be equally non-specific.

You'll want to compile a list of files from your folder using `glob`, `scandir` or similar. Likewise you will want to compile a list of files in the database.

Compare the two to identify those in the folder, but not in the database.

**Edit**

The output you're getting `.` and `..` are because filesystems have links to the current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directory. Typically you write code to skip these values.

For example, taking your code:

```
$files1 = scandir($directory)

if ($files1) {
    foreach ($files1 as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, ['.', '..'])) continue;

        // Your other code...
    }
}
```

Comment: @ElectronicsForKTU - I have edited my answer to help you with your problem.